# jquery change first part of input value with dropdown value

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, dropdown

My html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Volvo,4 wheels, hardtop"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Volvo,4 wheels, hardtop"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the first word of the value in the checkbox to be the same as the word selected in the dropdown. But only in the same row. So if the value in the dropdown of the first row is 'Saab', the value in the second row shouldn't be automatically 'Saab' but could be a different value.
How can i do this?

Comment: You can keep them separate with each having a distinct ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for easy visualization of change i changed checkbox to text, here you can change to `type=text` to `type=checkbox`

```
 $("select").change(function() {
        var setTarget= $(this).parent().prev().find("input[type=text]");
        var splitVal = setTarget.val().split(",");
        var sliceVal = splitVal.slice(1, splitVal.length).join(",");
        setTarget.val($(this).find('option:selected').text()+","+sliceVal);
    });
```

you can use the code for proceeding with your requirement..
https://jsfiddle.net/havt1qbz/1/

Comment: Ok and what if the values after the first comma are randomly generated with php?

Comment: first i have the value generated with php, then i'd like to change the first value with jquery

Comment: yup.. the edit is for the same cause.. try and let me know.

Comment: after changing the dropdown value i get "saab," (no caps and nothing behind it)

Comment: didn't get you.. will you post a fiddle as per your requirement and as per my edit.

Comment: see the updated jsfiddle with your updated code, if you look in 'inspect element' you'll see that the value isn't changing, but there is an id added to the td-element.

Comment: hey buddy, check my fiddle in answer. i edited it long back.

Comment: sorry i didn't see it. but it has to be a checkbox with a value, not text.

Comment: ha ha ha.. :D i have mentioned in my comment, for easy visualization i did it.. you can make changes accordingly,, read it completely, you will find answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this??

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="chk01" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Volvo,4 wheels, hardtop"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="s01">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="chk02" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Volvo,4 wheels, hardtop"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="s02">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Show checked results" id="btnShow"/>

    <script>
$('#s01').change(function(){//selectbox 01 change event
    var select_val = $( "#s01 option:selected" ).val();
    var checkbox_val = $('#chk01').val();
    var part_of_val = checkbox_val.split(',');
    checkbox_val =select_val+', '+part_of_val[1]+', '+part_of_val[2];
    $('#chk01').val(checkbox_val);
});
$('#s02').change(function(){//selectbox 02 change event
    var select_val = $( "#s02 option:selected" ).val();
    var checkbox_val = $('#chk02').val();
    var part_of_val = checkbox_val.split(',');
    checkbox_val =select_val+', '+part_of_val[1]+', '+part_of_val[2];
    $('#chk02').val(checkbox_val);
});
$('#btnShow').click(function(){// button click event
    if($('#chk01').is(':checked')){
        alert($('#chk01').val());
    }
    if($('#chk02').is(':checked')){
        alert($('#chk02').val());
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: can't work with id. This is just an example, but in real time i've to work with a very big by php generated table.

Comment: names are all the same. its generated with a foreach loop in php. multiple loops, so adding $x in id will get you multiple id="0"